# File renameTo & File.delete

Tags: java, file, file-moving

I have been writing a program for batch system using quartz and i find a problem,

```
if(!file.renameTo(new File(PATH_FILE_PROCESSED+file.getName())))System.out.println("Cannot Move File :"+file.getAbsolutePath());
else{
    if(!file.delete())System.out.println("Cannot Delete File :"+file.getAbsolutePath());    
}
```

i want to move file from one directory to another directory but i can't delete the file in the same process, from my analysis i think the file haven't finished copying then running the file.delete();
my question is, is there a way to wait until the file finished copying then run the file.delete? 
thanks

Comment: Reading your code, it looks like you go into the `else` block when the `renameTo` call *succeeds*. So, the file does not exist at its original location anymore. So, you cannot delete it from its original location, because it isn't there anymore.

Comment: no renameTo in java actually copying the file not moving the file thats why i want to delete when it succeed

Comment: If `File.renameTo` copies the file on your computer rather than renaming it, than you have a problem on your platform - it's not supposed to do that. The same problem may also impact the operation of the delete.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming is almost instant as it doesn't copy the file, it just moves which directory it appears in (unless you are moving between filesystems)

On windows, you can't rename or delete if you have the file open somewhere. Make sure you have close()ed it properly.

Comment: thanks for answering @Peter Lawrey but i java.io.File doesnt have close() command do you have any other way?

Comment: If closing the file is the real problem here try to look for some `InputStream`s (or `OutputStream`), `BufferedReader`, things you could have used to read/write the file.

Comment: @NoobatPrograming Where are you processing the files?

Comment: @PeterLawrey above that code the process is unziping the file then insert all file to db then running these code,

Comment: @NoobatPrograming That is the code you need to fix to ensure the files have been closed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i think i use zip4j to extract my file and now looking for a way maybe because in zip4j the file still open

Comment: @NoobatPrograming possibly.

Answer (score 0):

i think i already found the problem, the problem is when i insert the the file inside zip some other code already insert the data so it create duplicate in database and it create an error like this. so thanks for answering the question